# How does CI affect semantic versioning?

Tags: continuous-integration, semantic-versioning

In [Countinous Delivery book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912), it's recommended to keep everything - including CI scripts - in the version control. Actually, current CI systems like *gitlab CI* already follow this rule of thumb and search for CI scripts in the same codebase.
On the other hand, we are versioning our codebase (and it's built artifacts) whenever it changes. And we follow semantic versioning for that; incrementing *patch* field for bugfixes, *minor* for non-breaking features, and so on...
And we make sure the version is incremented between commits by checking it in the CI.
But, there are commits that only change the CI scripts; i.e. adding an analysis job, optimizing another, etc.
My question, after this long boring preface, is that what is the best practice to versioning such changes to the CI? Since it **possibly** can affect the final built artifact (e.g. changing a build flag in the CI job for optimization or ...).
Is it ok to increment the version in this case?

Comment: Versioning the content of the git repo is redundant.  Ask yourself, what is it you're using SemVer to version?  Is it the package output of your product or just the API?  Are there multiple API's packages produced from this code base?

Comment: Are you saying that every commit into your git repo changes the semver of your package? I want to make sure that I understand your preface and question correctly.

Comment: @g7p, no, I am saying that git already has the commit hash for that purpose. It's arguably okay to apply a SemVer label to a git hash, but what exactly are you versioning with that label? The git hash or some other random content in the repo?  If the labels containing the SemVer strings, also include a reference to the API or package target that the string applies to, that's fine. Remember, it's a version (git hash) of the repo that provides the machinery and fodder for the production of the versioned product. Adding the git hash to the build meta tag on the output side, is always correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Git is a revision control system. Every time you commit something to a git repo, it labels the content of the repo with a content hash value that represents that version of the repo.  Semantic versioning of a git repo's content is redundant and pointless.  The whole point of SemVer is to provide a means for producers to communicate risk to consumers.  In other words, semantic versioning is intended for build product labeling, not the bits that go into producing the build.

If you attempt to apply [SemVer](https://semver.org) semantics to the repo, you are labeling the product inputs, not the product itself.  You should not apply a SemVer string until after all unit/regression/acceptance tests have been performed.  How else can you have any certainty whether the code/build-script changes have broken anything?

---

Pre-build labeling cannot work.  Build processes that are capable of reproducing the exact same output twice in a row, are extremely rare, if any exist at all.  It is a violation of best practice to have multiple API's/packages in the world with the same SemVer string attached to them.  If you label the repo content and then forward that label to the build output, every time you run the build, you produce a package with different content.  There will always be some risk that more than one of those outputs will be released into the wild.  Many security conscious consumers pay close attention to the content hash of packages they consume.  Detecting that a particular producer has released multiple package hashes without bumping the version number, will raise red flags and lead to mistrust of that producers internal processes.

---

This is a very deep topic that can't be fully covered here.  Other issues to consider are OS/Compiler/Tool chain updates.  Will you also be committing the entire build tool chain to the same repo?  This is an untenable approach, full of hazards I cannot fully enumerate, without taking a few months off work to document them.

Best practice:

- Use semantic commit messages that clearly state the developer's intent.
- Validate build outputs prior to packaging/labeling.
- Always keep humans in the loop, for non-prerelease publications.

---

Just for clarity, let me add that maintaining build scripts and tool manifests in the repo is considered a best practice. It ties the versions of your scripts and tools, to the versions of the code you are building. Git does do this job quite well, by creating a commit hash that encompasses the state of the entire repo (minus the tags if I recall correctly). But there will be issues eventually, with older versions of tools, being withdrawn from file shares/feeds, particularly when they are found to create security vulnerabilities.

It will sometimes be the case, that older versions of your products, cannot be reproduced using the earlier build process. Checking in the binaries is often promoted as a fix for this issue, but I would argue that it's an anti-pattern. Binaries you are likely never going to want or need in the future, should not be stored in your repo. It just clogs everything up.

Consider using an alternate archival system. Maintaining a separate archive of older tools isn't a bad idea, but you will often find that you simply can't run them on current hardware and OS's, without significant reconfiguration of build machine(s) and re-introducing well known security risks. You should frequently prune such an archive, based on the latest known risks and weighing the cost of having to do some additional work, if/when the day ever comes, that you need to build from a really old commit hash.

It is better to maintain an up-to-date build system, that can build all of your code base, back to some reasonable point in its history. That point is usually the oldest bits that you are willing to actively support with bug fixes.

Comment: I used to work with a guy who pointed out that we should first build our tools, then use those to build our product dependencies and outputs.  He's right, but that's just not economically feasible.  In his world, you'd just need an integer to bump on each build.  SemVer is intended for a world where we don't build literally everything used to produce our products.

Comment: +1 for "Always keep humans in the loop, for non-prerelease publications." - aka. for any thing going out to consumers, always employ human gates. Automation can and should be used to help the human, but scripts should not be the sole arbiter.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable for prerelease versions to be released to consumers.  According to [SemVer](https://semver.org), all bets are off with regard to the semantics of the version triple, for any prerelease version.

Answer (score 3):

These days I'm using SemVer compatible Headver; https://github.com/line/HeadVer and feeling happy.

It is very CI friendly thanks to the automatic incremental versioning, but still be able to announce when breaking changes happens by allowing to define major version number manually.